# Write numpy matrix to csv file in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to write out a csv file that outputs a 5,9 matrix using the following code

```
result_array=np.empty((5,9))
for i in range(tbl4.shape[0]):
    get_angles=tbl4[i,[13,14,15]]
    rot_mat=t3d.euler2mat(*radians(get_angles),'rzxz').reshape(1,9)   
    result_array=np.append(result_array,[rot_mat],axis=0)
```

However,

```
print(result_array)
```

does not return a value. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong and wouldnt mind getting some help on fixing this code.

Thanks in advance!

tbl4 is 5x16 matrix

```
[[ 1.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
   1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
   1.640000e+03  3.110000e+03  1.780000e+03  8.712900e+00  1.422611e+02
  -1.023384e+02]
 [ 1.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
   1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
   1.750000e+03  2.890000e+03  1.810000e+03  3.789880e+01  7.270230e+01
   8.854010e+01]
 [ 1.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  3.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
   1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
   1.870000e+03  3.180000e+03  1.450000e+03  1.392469e+02  8.402020e+01
  -1.192579e+02]
 [ 1.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  4.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
   1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
   1.990000e+03  2.960000e+03  1.490000e+03  1.299047e+02  1.094238e+02
   1.722355e+02]
 [ 1.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
   1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
   1.750000e+03  2.970000e+03  1.410000e+03 -1.648163e+02  7.195840e+01
  -8.448190e+01]]
```

Comment: Can you share the sample values of ```tbl4```?

Comment: We can't tell what your code needs to look like just from this. We can see some red flags, like creating a 5x9 "empty" array and then *appending* to it instead of writing into the existing cells, but we'd need to see a [mcve] to say anything definitive.

Comment: @ user2357112 so true

Comment: the code runs upto here ```rot_mat=t3d.euler2mat(*radians(get_angles),'rzxz').reshape(1,9)```
however when i try to write this out to a file, only the matrix for the last iteration get written.

Comment: what is ```t3d```?

Comment: t3d is module that converts degrees into a rotation matrix

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for pointing that out. changing the empty array size from 5,9 to 0,9 fixed my problem.